# List the files Sublime's "Find in Files" is searching in

Tags: sublimetext

Sublime's "*Find in Files*" (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) feature can become very slow if there are any huge files in the folder being searched. When this happens, I try to use the *Where:* field to filter out such files...

[image: Screenshot showing the Where field populated]

... but sometimes I miss some big files, and the search is still very slow. Since the files that are slowing down the search don't necessarily end up showing up in the search results, it can be tough to understand the cause and fix it.

When this happens, it'd be convenient to just be able to list all the files that Sublime is searching in, so I can look down the list and try to spot which extra files I should be excluding.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any official feature to do this, but there's a simple hack: do a regex search for `\A`, which matches only the start of a file:

[image: Another Find in Files screenshot, with regex search enabled (and circled) and with \A entered in the "Find:" field]

This will list every file that isn't filtered out by your *Where:* filter, and will do so quickly, since Sublime doesn't have to search through the entire content of any large files.